# R rep function for weights

Tags: r

Could you please help me understand the code below? I understand the first line of it. It creates a series of 1 till the number of rows in a dataset. I didn't get the meaning of the second line of code.

```
weight <- rep(1, nrow(dataTraining))
weight[dataTraining$SeriousDlqin2yrs == 0] <- 0.1
```

`SeriousDlqin2yrs` is a target variable.

Comment: It's replacing the weight of 1 with 0.1 when `SeriousDlqin2yrs` is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct on what the first row does.

Suppose your training data has 10 rows. Let's do a quick simulation:

```
dataTraining <- data.frame(SeriousDlqin2yrs = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Then your data frame looks like this:

```
dataTraining
#    SeriousDlqin2yrs
# 1                 0
# 2                 0
# 3                 0
# 4                 0
# 5                 0
# 6                 0
# 7                 1
# 8                 0
# 9                 1
# 10                0
```

And we have `nrow(dataTraining)` equal to 10 as expected.

When you construct the `weight` vector, it's repeating the number 1 until you get a 10-element vector.

```
weight <- rep(1, nrow(dataTraining))
weight
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The `weight` vector lines up with `dataTraining` since they have the same number of elements.

Now suppose you want to change the weight for observations where `SeriousDlqin2yrs` is equal to 0. You can subset a vector based on another vector of the same length like this:

```
vector1[<condition involving vector2>]
```

This returns all elements of the first vector where the condition on the second vector returns `TRUE`. Since `weight` matches up with `dataTraining`, we can subset `weight` based on `SeriousDlqin2yrs` in a similar fashion. The condition we want is `SeriousDlqin2yrs == 0`.

Let's take a look at `weight` and `SeriousDlqin2yrs` side-by-side and mark the places where `SeriousDlqin2yrs == 0` returns `TRUE`.

```
#                   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# SeriousDlqin2yrs     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1     0
# weight               1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#                      ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    x    ^    x     ^
```

Here `^` means it's true, `x` means it's false. So if we do

```
weight[dataTraining$SeriousDlqin2yrs == 0]
```

we get elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, and 10 of `weight`.

Great. That's what we want. But now we want to give a new weight to those values. As it turns out, it's as easy as telling R to assign the new weight to that subset.

```
weight[dataTraining$SeriousDlqin2yrs == 0] <- 0.1
weight
#[1] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 1.0 0.1 1.0 0.1
```

Note that elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, and 10 are now 0.1, while elements 7 and 9 are still 1. That's exactly what we want!

**In summary**, It's replacing the weight of 1 with 0.1 when `SeriousDlqin2yrs` is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

First line is creating a vector of 1s that has the length of the number of rows in dataTraining.

Second line is assigning the value 0.1 in that same vector to the correspoding index where values in dataTraining$SeriousDlqin2yrs is equal to 0.

Remember that columns are essentially a list of vectors in a data frame. The $ sign between the table name and the column name treats that specified column like a plain old vector.

example...

```
SeriousDlqin2yrs <- rep(c(1, 0), 3)
> SeriousDlqin2yrs
[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0
> weight <- rep(1.0, 6)
> weight
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
> weight[SeriousDlqin2yrs == 0] <- 0.1
> weight
[1] 1.0 0.1 1.0 0.1 1.0 0.1
```